# MySQL server not responding to "show databases" or some other commands

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I open command prompt, move to my wamp/bin/mysql/bin directory and type

```
mysql -u root
```

since there is no password it logs in correctly, but when I type in

```
show databases
```

all I get is

```
->
->
->
```

until I click control+C

[Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd5ZJ.png)

Comment: Have you tried `show databases;`? I think that you need the last character **;** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a trailing semi-colon (`;`):

```
show databases;
```

It's waiting at the prompt because it thinks you haven't completed the statement yet. You could put a `;` on a line by itself at this point and the full command would execute.

Comment: oh my. Thank you *disconnects in shame*

Comment: In my case, having a semi-colon attached produces the same result.